# Meaning of closed under sub objects and quotient object

Tags: category-theory

$\mathcal {B}$ is an exact abelian subcategory of an abelian category $\mathcal {A}$ such that $\mathcal {B}$ is closed in $\mathcal {A}$ under subobjects and quotient objects. I am not able to grasp what the author wants to say by this closed property?

Does it mean that any quotient of objects in $\mathcal {B}$ is in $\mathcal {A}$? I am a little bit confused.

I was trying to see via example of category of **R/I** modules $\subset$ category of **R** modules. But again does the closed property actually imply that every **R/I** module is an **R** module and any quotient of **R/I** module is also an **R** module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\mathbf{O}$ is an object in $\mathcal{B}$. Then it is also an object in $\mathcal{A}$. What "closed under subobojects" means is that if $\mathbf{O'}$ is a subobject of $\mathbf{O}$ in $\mathcal{A}$, then $\mathbf{O'}$ is also an object in $\mathcal{B}$, and it is also a subobject of $\mathbf{O}$ in $\mathcal{B}$.

Similarly, "closed under quotients": if $\mathbf{Q}$ is a quotient of $\mathbf{O}$ in $\mathcal{A}$, then $\mathbf{Q}$ is also an object in $\mathcal{B}$, where it is also a quotient of $\mathbf{O}$.

For your example: let $M$ be an $R/I$ module. Then viewing it as an $R$-module, it has $R$-submodules and $R$-quotient modules. But every $R$-submodule $N$ of $M$ is also an $R/I$-submodule of $M$; and every $R$-quotient module $Q$ of $M$ is also an $R/I$-quotient module of $M$.

Comment: @57Jimmy: Do me a favor and don't insert commentary like "clearly" into my answers.

Comment: I beg your pardon, I just thought that it was not entirely clear what the author means and what follows automatically from it, which is why I tried to clarify it. I'll undo it if you prefer

Comment: @57Jimmy: I've already edited. Note that in fact your addition of "clearly" is **incorrect**: it is **not** the case that just because a subcategory contains a subobject it contains it *as* a subobject: you also need certain morphisms to be in the subcategory. So by adding "clearly" you not only added an error, you also make it seem like not realizing that "this" is the case (even though it may not be the case in general) means missing the obvious.

Comment: Ok, fair. Sorry for it. I guess I started correcting some things that I thought would be confusing and then got carried away...

Comment: Got it, thank you. I felt this definition had something hidden now I understand. thanks again.